# how to move fotoroma navigation thumbnail vertical to horizontal in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7

how to move fotoroma navigation thumbnail vertical to horizontal to the bottom of the main image in magento 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check-in your theme's view.xml file here,

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Vendor]/[Theme]/etc/view.xml

and replace the "**navdir**" to "**horizontal**"

Check this line in your view.xml in `<var name="gallery">`

```
<var name="navdir">horizontal</var> <!-- Sliding direction of thumbnails (horizontal/vertical) -->
```

Or if are you using the custom premium theme there will be an option in the configuration to change the navigation thumbnail vertical or horizontal.

To change the thumbnail position in the Codazon Infinity theme, Please follow the below settings.

> Admin-> Codazon-> Flexible Theme-> Settings-> Config the Activated
>   theme-> Theme Configuration-> Pages-> Product View and change the
>
> **More View Slider Style** to **Horizontal**

Check the below image

[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i can see in the view.xml file where the horizontal for navdir has alredy been there still no changes

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: unlimited codazon infinity theme

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check

Comment: ok let me check Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's working but can i customize the layout of the fotroma gallery

Comment: Yes, You can customize using CSS

Comment: Please accept the answer if this answer helps you to resolve your issue, So this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link for your help :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703753/how-to-set-fotorama-thumbnail-as-vertical/39716688#39716688

I hope it helps...